# Delphi generic nested classes

Tags: delphi, generics

I was doing a comparison between C++ and Delphi and I found something tricky to me.

This is very easy C++ code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class C {

 class D {
  T x;
 }

}
```

In this scenario, we have that the class `C` is a template class ( = generic class) and the nested class `D` is also a template class. If `T` is a `double`, the `x` inside `D` is `double`.

I cannot say this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class C {

 template<typename T>
 class D {
  T x;
 }

}
```

That is an error since I am already "inside" `C` and another `T` would be a conflict. To fix the error, I should use a different name, like `U`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class C {

 template<typename U>
 class D {
  T x;
 }

}
```

In Delphi, I could write this:

```pascal
type
 TClassC<T> = class
  private

   type
    TClassD = class
     private 
      x: T;
    end;

 end;
```

If `T` is an `integer`, now `x` is an `integer` since (from what I've understood reading online) the `TClassD` is `integer`. In Delphi this is also legal:

```pascal
type
 TClassC<T> = class
  private

   type
    TClassD<T> = class // <-- note the <T> repeated!!
     private 
      x: T;
    end;

 end;
```

What about now? If I am able to declare `T` again in `TClassD`, this means that without the `<T>` I'd have a non-generic `TClassD` class.  Am I correct?

Comment: Should be easy enough for you to check this, but I'd expect that if this code compiles, the inner T hides the outer one. So it's just like you used a different name for your inner type parameter. Like `TClassC<T1>`  and then `TClassD<T2>`.

Comment: In other words, my expectation is that the Delphi code behaves exactly as your C++ version with no clashing parameter names. But the C++ language protects you from name clashes.

Comment: In your first C++ example, `D` is itself not a template class, the template from `C` is just in scope so `D` can use it. In your second C++ example, having two template parameters both named `T` is indeed a naming conflict, because C++ doesn't like repeating identifiers in the same scope. Delphi Generics are not the same thing as C++ templates (even though they use similar syntax), and Delphi is a little more flexible in this particular example than C++ is.

Comment: Thank you both david and remy. Also @RemyLebeau your "little more flexible" means that it allows the declaration of nested types with the same parameter? In this case by the way I'd expect that both classes (like in my last example) have the same type!

Comment: @Raffaele: not with the **same parameter** (that would be useless), just with the same **name** for a parameter. As David said, it very likely hides the outer `T`. If so, I would use different names too.

Comment: @Raffaele: it is probably similar to nested procedures. If you give these a parameter with the same name as an outer variable or parameter, it hides the outer one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It turns out to be even stranger that I expected, see my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider this simple program:

```
type
  TClassC<T> = class
  private
    type
    TClassD<T> = class
    private
      x: T;
    end;
  end;

var
  obj: TClassC<Integer>.TClassD<string>;

begin
  obj := TClassC<Integer>.TClassD<string>.Create;
  obj.x := 42;
end.
```

This program compiles, but emits the following hint:

> [dcc32 Hint]: H2509 Identifier 'T' conflicts with type parameters of container type

The assignment proves that `x` takes its type from the outer generic parameter rather than the inner.

I have to say that this surprised me because I was expecting the opposite. I was expecting that the inner generic parameter would *hide* the outer. In fact, so far as I can tell, there is no way for the inner type to refer to its generic parameter.

In order to be able to refer to both generic parameters you would need to use different names for them. For instance:

```
type
  TClassC<T1> = class
  private
    type
    TClassD<T2> = class
    private
      x: T2;
    end;
  end;
```

This is what the analagous C++ template code forces you to do.

In my view, it is a design weakness of the Delphi language that you are permitted to compile the code at the top of this answer.

Comment: that is indeed very unexpected.

Comment: That is surprising.  Though it does reinforce the notion that hints and warnings should generally just be treated as though they were errors, even if in some cases the compiler will still run to completion.

Comment: @J... I find the hint very surprising. If anything that's the most perplexing aspect of this. That the developers have been sufficiently aware of the issue as to raise a hint, but then leave it at that. What were they thinking? Having got as far as realising this was an issue, they decided to leave the compiler as it is, accepting generic classes where the generic parameter can never be used?

Comment: Well this is tricky. I was going to write a class for a double linked list and I found this weird behavior

Comment: Make sure you compile with hints on, and then deal with them!